# Playa field search feature displaying entries from all channels

Tags: matrix, playa, filter

I have a Matrix field with a Playa field inside it, listing entries limited to the "Biographies" channel. The issue I'm seeing is that when editors search for a title, the resulting list contains entries from ALL channels.

Is this intended behaviour or is there something I am missing? Ultimately, searching the entries should respect the settings for that field and only list our "Biographies" channel's entry titles.

**EE 2.8.1

Playa 4.5.1

Matrix 2.6**

edit: to clarify, the field is in the CP, as shown below. If I search for "Pinchas Zukerman", all matching entry titles in the system are displayed

[image]

Comment: Please clarify where editors are searching exactly.

Comment: **Update:** I created another field with the same configuration(Playa inside a Matrix) and it seems the problem is only happening when "Allow multiple selections" is _not_ selected in the field's settings.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to be reported to the developer.